# Working on two-dimensional arrays to calculate win/lose

Tags: javascript, algorithm, trading

I am tracking my trading portfolio in two arrays of objects.

The sells and the buys for a specific trade currency as follows:

```javascript
var sell {
    sold_amount: sold,
    bought_amount: bought,
    price : price
}


var buy {
    sold_amount: sold,
    bought_amount: bought,
    price : price
}
```

I am trying to the following:

Calculate my win-lose percentage in a [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) manner. That means that I want to take the latest sell I made and start subtracting the price/amount from the latest buy and then move backwards.

If my sell was big enough, it would mean that I would need to look not only on the previous buy, but I would need to search an unknown number of previous buys until all my sell amount is exhausted so that I can calculate my win/lose.

My difficulty is that since sells and buys are done on different amount/prices, it is really difficult for me to calculate the result.

That means for example:

```
I bought 20 units of  $javascript paying 32 units of $c++ ,
I bought 17 units of  $javascript paying 29 units of $c++ ,
I sold   57 units of  $c++        paying 31 units of $javascript,
I bought 22 units of $javascript  paying 22 units of c++,
I sold   12 units of  c++         paing  11 units of $javascript,
```

That means that at every sell I would need to look backwards and see the price I bought it recursively and calculate the win/lose according to the amount sold/bought.

I am not looking for a solution, just some guidelines or some advice.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but why not try to convert them all to a common value they both share - like, say, money? Wouldn't that make the calculations simpler? Plus, you're not really paying for one stock with another - that in itself seems like a sort of distortion of the model.

Comment: Could you give some test cases? So i mean some valid javascript inputs and what you would expect the code to return?

Comment: there are no units in your sell or buy object, maybe put an example of your js data

Comment: Yea, at least 5-10 test cases would help us in finding the solution for your problem.

Comment: `'c++'` !== `'$c++'`? or is it a typo?

Comment: The syntax highlighter here does not seem to like `price : price`. What is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the transactions and maintain two indicators for total units and total price. The selling price does not matter for the calculation of the actually bought products.

Please have a look to [FIFO and LIFO accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting).

To get an actual value with some sold items, the last buy is checked and if the last amount of units is smaller or equal to the sold units, the total values are updated, as well as the actual unit, until all units are taken from the latest buy.

If some buy has a rest of units, then this information is added to the items array.

As result, a dynamic array is maintained with the last purchases buys and sales.

```
                                                  ------------------
                                                       t o t a l
 action     units     price     calc      price     units     price   comment
--------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  -----------------
  buy         20        32     20 * 32      640       20       640
  buy         17        29     17 * 29      493       37      1133
  sell        22        22    -17 * 29     -493       20       640    take last first
                              - 5 * 32     -160       15       480    take next to last
  buy         31        57     31 * 57     1767       46      2247
  sell        11        12    -11 * 57     -627       35      1620
                                                  ------------------
```

```js
var transactions = [
        { action: 'buy', product: 'foo', units: 20, price: 32 },
        { action: 'buy', product: 'foo', units: 17, price: 29 },
        { action: 'sell', product: 'foo', units: 22, price: 22 },
        { action: 'buy', product: 'foo', units: 31, price: 57 },
        { action: 'sell', product: 'foo', units: 11, price: 12 }
    ],
    accounts = {};

transactions.forEach(({ action, product, units, price }) => {
    var last;
    accounts[product] = accounts[product] || { items: [], totalUnits: 0, totalPrice: 0 };

    if (action === 'buy') {
        accounts[product].totalUnits += units;
        accounts[product].totalPrice += units * price;
        accounts[product].items.push({ units, price });
    } else {
        while (units) {
            last = accounts[product].items.pop();
            if (last.units <= units) {
                accounts[product].totalUnits -= last.units;
                accounts[product].totalPrice -= last.units * last.price;
                units -= last.units;
                continue;
            }
            accounts[product].totalUnits -= units;
            accounts[product].totalPrice -= units * last.price;
            last.units -= units;
            units = 0;
            accounts[product].items.push(last);
        }
    }
    console.log(accounts);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: c++ and $c++ was indeed a typo.Thanks for the answer, but this only captures the change of each unit in comparison to itself. LIFO is important because for example, if i bought a stock one time 10 $ and then i bought again 20 $ and then i sold 1 for 20 $ , I want to use the last price bought to make the comparison and move backwards

Comment: What do you mean by *"readed to the items array"*? *"read from the items array"*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, sorry for being unclear, it was ment to be *readded*, but now i change the sentence to *If some buy has a rest of units, then this information is added to the items array.*

Answer (score 0):

If we think of LIFO trading we can translate that to the idea of elements in a data structure called a stack, which have the operations push/pop:

[image: LIFO Example, curiosity of wikipedia]

Each trade has five variables: buy amount, buy type, sell amount, sell type, and date.

```
function Trade(buyAmount, buyType, sellAmount, sellType, date) {

    this.buyAmount = buyAmount;
    this.buyType = buyType;
    this.sellAmount = sellType;
    this.date = date;

}
```

This is a JavaScript object constructor, and it can be called by saying:

`var trade = new Trade("Bitcoin", 1.0, "Ethereum", 10.0, new Date("5/30/2018"));`

The keyword `new` before a function call creates an object and `this` used in that function becomes a reference to that new object. The object is then assigned to the variable `trade`. (Research `this` it is very powerful.)

Anyway, next you would need to create an array sorted by date and create an algorithm that could keep trade of the gross profit of each trade related to the type of item sold, that is, an dictionary resembling:

`var profit = { Bitcoin: 0, Ethereum: 0 }`

This is is a good starting place, and I used this same kind of data structure to calculate the taxes for my cryptocurrency gains in 2017.